# How to make a UIImageView move using a DX and DY variable?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Currently, here is my code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {


var dx : CGFloat = 0
var dy : CGFloat = 0

@IBOutlet var sprite: UIImageView!


@IBAction func A(sender: AnyObject) {

    dx = -1;
}
@IBAction func W(sender: AnyObject) {


    dy = -1;
}
@IBAction func D(sender: AnyObject) {


    dx = 1;
}
@IBAction func S(sender: AnyObject) {


    dy = 1;
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backgroundThread(delay: 10
        , background: {
        while(true){

            self.sprite.frame.origin.x += self.dx;

            self.sprite.frame.origin.x += self.dy;


        }

    })


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

And here is the backgroundThread function (which does work. I tested with a simple println()):

```
func backgroundThread(delay: Double = 0.0, background: (() -> Void)? = nil, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
    if(background != nil){ background!(); }

    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if(completion != nil){ completion!(); }
    }
}
}
```

For some reason, when I press any of my buttons, it does not start moving. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: omg my eyes. Why not use NSTimer?

Comment: Right now I'm just worried about why nothing is happening on button presses. Also, why wouldn't I use a async background thread? What is the benefit of a NSTimer above a new thread?

Comment: First off, you never wanna use a while true to update UI because it will freeze the thread. Secondly, the while true loop isnt even running on the main thread, UI only update on the main thread. You have to use NSTimer in this case Im afraid.

Comment: I just tried it with a NSTimer and it is working! Can you go into more detail as to why the UI only updates on the main thread? When would I want to use a background thread instead of a NSTimer?

Comment: Apple has made it that way that UI ONLY update on the main thread. For that decision you'll have to mix knowledge and creativity ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help!